Why does the integral manifold of the distribution of a flat connection cover the base?
I'm reading "Geometry of Characteristic Classes" by Shigeyuki Morita. Specifically, I'm going over the second chapter "Characteristic Classes of Flat Bundles." The beginning of the chapter goes over the definition of principal $G$-bundles and connections and then gives equivalent characterizations of flat connections. In part 2.1.4, he states the following

We give another equivalent description of flat bundles[...] Let $\pi:P\rightarrow M$ be a principal $G$-bundle with a flat connection $\omega$ and let $\mathcal{H}$ be the corresponding completely integrable distribution. Then, for each point $u$ on $P$ if we denote by $L_u$ the maximal integral manifold passing through it, then the projection $\pi:L_u\rightarrow M$ becomes a covering map

I don't understand why $\pi:L_u\rightarrow M$ a covering map?

Do you know that the parallel translate of an element of the fiber of $P$ over the base point around a loop $\gamma$ in $M$ depends only on the homotopy class of $\gamma$?

@TedShifrin yes I do. I think I should be showing that the map $\pi:L_u\rightarrow M$ is a principal $\operatorname{Hol}(P,u)$-bundle.

I'm thinking about it more naïvely, but yes. Can you not argue directly that $\pi$ is a local diffeomorphism and an even covering?

@TedShifrin I can definitely argue that it is a local diffeomorphism. It has injective differential and the dimension of $L_u$ is the same as that of $M$ and I can show it's surjective by the horizontal lifting property. I'm struggling to show that it's an even covering. What should I choose to be evenly covered here?
